# What are the Risks of using app with dangerous delegated permissions in azure?

Tags: azure-active-directory, permissions, privileges, delegation, phishing

What are the risks in using an app with dangerous delegated permissions - besides luring a privileged user to connect the app and use his privileges?

Are there any known dangerous delegated permissions that a low privileged user (attacker) can use?

Comment: Using an app with dangerous delegated permissions can cause Privacy Violations, Data leakage, Unauthorized access. For example Mail.ReadWrite permission can allow a low privileged user to read and modify emails in their own mailbox and User.ReadWrite.All permission can allow a low privileged user to modify user accounts, which can be used to gain unauthorized access to other accounts

Comment: I am not sure that Mail.ReadWrite can help here because if the it enables the app to change only mails that the user can change, so there are no any benefit with that. I am sorry, I meant the mention that the weak user is a malicious actor. As of User.ReadWrite.All, I guess that the app won't be able to call the real dangerous apis because the user is weak and does not have any role.

Comment: I gave them as examples to explain, what is your exact requirement could you brief?

Comment: yep, I wonder if a weak attacker (without any role) in the directory can use  application with delegated permissions (whatever permissions) to do serious actions (DOS/escalation/initial access etc...). Something that can't be done by the user himself. If there is nothing that can be done, I wonder why microsoft wrote that DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All is dangerous

Comment: It Allows the app to manage permission grants for delegated permissions exposed by any API (including Microsoft Graph), on behalf of the signed in user.

Comment: I see. And yet, can it do things that the signed in user can not do interactively?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257099/discussion-between-adi-ml-and-rukmini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** that: The normal user will not be having privileges to perform action on the tenant.

A normal user cannot create resources, cannot access mails of all users, cannot update user profiles, cannot access the user's OneDrive files, cannot send mail on behalf of the user, Performing Operations on Azure AD, Reading and Writing Data, Managing Resources but if the app has delegated permissions, then the user will be able to do it.

For example, the normal user will not be having privileges to update the user profiles.

But if the application has **`User.ReadWrite.All`** API permission, and the user authenticates with the application then the user will be able to successfully update the user profile.

[image]

The user will be able to update other user profiles:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "businessPhones": [
    "xxx"
  ],
  "officeLocation": "xxx"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this POC, got access denied. Are you sure that the user is a weak one (without any roles) and the app does not have any role?

Comment: Yes the user without any roles and permissions is a weak

Comment: For some reason, I still get 403 forbidden - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. the app got 
User.ReadWrite.All, User.ReadWrite, 
profile, 
openid,  
offline_access,  
email, 
all are delegated and got an admin consent. tried with both graph explorer and postman. when I try to use the same api you noted as GET, it works.

Comment: Yes you have to use the API if you are granting permissions to the app and trying to update user

Comment: If you want to do it via portal then assign user administrator role to the user

Comment: yep, and then you turn the weak user into a privileged user - which is not what we try to do

Comment: Yes then the user will be able to update the profile via API with required API permissions only

Comment: I see, so it does not help me much (because I wanted  to check if a weak user- without turning him into a privileged one, can do some  privileged actions with delegated permissions ).

Comment: The weak user without roles can do few actions with delegated permissions

Comment: This answers the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just note in your answer there that you granted the "weak" user more privileges (another role)

Comment: Yes sure will check that